# Javascript Pause Loop Until function is finished

Tags: javascript

I am trying to loop a function but I need the loop to pause, execute the function, then continue the loop. The function takes around 1 to 5 minutes to finish. Then I want to unpause the loop and redo the function 20 times.

What I've tried so far:

```
for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    //Some function here
}
```

```
do {
var i = 0
// Some function here
i++
} while (i < 20)
```

Comment: it will be always like this unless your function is asynchronous

Comment: If you use asynchronous functions, you have to use Promises and chain them together

Comment: It depends on the type of function you use inside the loop. If it is synchronous, the loop wont iterate till it completes. If its asynchronous you need to await for it to wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function is asynchronous you could define the loop something like this to wait for the process to complete. For synchronous functions you dont have to do anything. The loop will automatically waits till it completes

```
async function doAll()
{
  for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    await heavyDutyFn()//this function should return a promise always
  }

}
```

Comment: Didn't work for some reason. Also my heavydutyfn() is async too. Should I remove it?

Comment: this is just an example depicting your situation. You should learn to create promises first which essentially uses for i/o operations

Comment: Did something like:  doFunc();async function rFunc(){//Function here}
async function doFunc() {for(i=0; i<20; i++){
                await rFunc()
            }
        }